# mysqli_query doesn't insert data into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, insert-into

Can someone find the problem?
It doesn't give any errors, but new rows don't appear in the database and I don't know the problem is.

```
  if (isset( $_REQUEST['signupnbtn'] ) ) {
    $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['ageinput']);
    $discord = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['discordinput']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['emailinput']);
    $tmp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['tmpinput']);
    $steam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['steaminput']);
    $datum = date("d-m-Y");
    $errorcode = 0;

    $q = "INSERT INTO `admissions` (age, discord, email, tmp, steam, datum)
    VALUES ('$age', '$discord', '$email', '$tmp', '$steam', '$datum')";
    $query2 = "SELECT email FROM `admissions` WHERE email='$email'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
    $countrows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if($countrows >= 1){
      $errorcode = 1;
    }else {
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$q);
    }
      if ($result) {
        $errorcode = 4;
      }

  }
```

Comment: what is the output of $countrows?does `mysqli_query($con,$q)` line get executed ?if so what is the output of $result? you have to debug this

Comment: Also, what is the type of the `age` column? You try to treat it as a string, but that sounds fishy for a column named `age`.

Comment: Please describe your problem a little bit more. Does it insert an empty row? Are you sure that you don't have typing errors in your input names?

Comment: Age column is a string

Comment: It doesn't insert anything into the database.

Comment: $countrows is 0. I'm not sure how to check the output of $result.

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Munging query strings lets in unexpected and hard-to-debug syntax errors (and makes the code harder to cache and makes the code subject to SQL injection).

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "INSERT INTO admissions (age, discord, email, tmp, steam, datum) VALUES ('$age', '$discord', '$email', '$tmp', '$steam', '$datum')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the date should be in "Y-m-d" format instead of "d-m-Y" as below:

```
if (isset( $_REQUEST['signupnbtn'] ) ) {
    $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['ageinput']);
    $discord = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['discordinput']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['emailinput']);
    $tmp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['tmpinput']);
    $steam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['steaminput']);
    $datum = date("Y-m-d");
    $errorcode = 0;
    $q = "INSERT INTO `admissions` (age, discord, email, tmp, steam, datum)
    VALUES ('$age', '$discord', '$email', '$tmp', '$steam', '$datum')";
    $query2 = "SELECT email FROM `admissions` WHERE email='$email'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
    $countrows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if($countrows >= 1){
      $errorcode = 1;
    }else {
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$q);
    }
      if ($result) {
        $errorcode = 4;
      }
  }
```